# Using Celery and Redis with my Django application

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery, celeryd

I would like to ask a question according to `Celery` and `Redis` with my `Django` application.
As I will explain further in details, I get some random issues with these applications.

**My environment:**

I'm using :

- Django 1.11.20
- django-redis 4.7.0 / redis >= 2.10.5
- celery 4.2.1

**My local context: (Ubuntu virtual machine)**

I have a celery task which send an email with export file when this file is larger than 70.000 objects. The process works fine and I get the expected email with link to download my file.

Celery is started **manually** : `celery -A main worker -l info`

**My dev context: (FreeBSD server)**

I have exactly the same process. But celery is daemonized on my server. I can execute celery service with : `service celeryd_app start`

When I launch my celery task, sometimes I need to click on the button some times before to see :

```
Received task: app.tasks.get_xls_export[64d31ba5-73d9-4048-b19a-a4902fd904d7]
```

But the main issue that I have is : My task send an email with a specific email template located in `/templates/email/email.html`.

***Sometimes it send this email template and sometimes it send an old template which doesn't exist in my project.***

**My question:**

Is it possible that `Celery/Redis` has been kept in memory an old template ? There is a way to clean cache for my specific service ? Because I have other celery services on my server according to other applications.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have pending tasks if you want to [clear the pending tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=purge#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks)

You can do by

```
from main.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```

or you can do `celery -A main purge`

If you want to discard tasks of specific queue you can do

`celery amqp queue.purge <queue name>`

Comment: I tried `app.control.purge()`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on my task. It looks like there is an old template stored somewhere (redis or celery) ..